# Programmatically setting bind variable "in" clause in Oracle SQL (ADF)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle-adf

I want to have a select statement as follows

```
select * from someTable
```

Then I need to programmatically set the where clause in my view object:

```
setWhereClause("department_ids in (:ids)");
setNamedWhereClauseParam("ids", [1,2,3]);
executeQuery();
```

Is this possible to do?

Thanks!

Comment: I find my ability to write working ADF pages is directly proportional to my ability to Google.  See http://java.net/projects/smuenchadf/sources/samples/content/VariableInListUsingDBFunction.zip.  The idea is to have ADF pass a comma separated list in a single variable and have the Oracle database be responsible for converting that to a `IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(...))` expression.

Comment: What is your ADF (JDeveloper) version ? If you with 12c, there is neat solution - custom operator. With 11g and earler versions, you will have to use @MatthewMcPeak 's solution or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RowQualifier to filter the rows using Where condition.

```
    RowQualifier rowQualifier = new RowQualifier(<your VO>);
    rowQualifier.setWhereClause(<in clause>);
    Row[] filteredRows = <your VO>.getFilteredRows(rowQualifier);
```

the filteredRows array will contain the target rows if found.